# Ecommerce: how to make some products view only

Tags: customer-community, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce, b2b, e-commerce

In a Salesforce B2B eCommerce Lightning, how can I make some products visible but not available for purchase depending on user type, account attribute and product attributes ?

Example) if a client (user type A) entitled to buy for his company has a motorbike and he logs in my eCommerce site he will be able to buy a motorbike helmet. However if he doesn't have the permission to buy (user type B) he will be able to see it but not to buy it.  Is that possible ?   -   Please help.

[image]

Thanks

Pablo

Comment: Is this CloudCraze or B2B Lightning Experience?

Comment: Hi Victor L, this is B2B Lightning Experience